# upper_bound With binary_function Visual Studio 2008 Bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, functor, upperbound, commutativity

1<sup>st</sup> of all, yes, I am stuck using Visual Studio 2008, and I believe this bug is specific to Visual Studio 2008.

I'm trying to write a functor to compare just 1 member of my struct so I can do `upper_bound` on a `vector` of said structs which is sorted by that member. That's hard to explain in words so here's an example:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    char b;
};

struct comp : binary_function<const double, const Foo&, bool> {
    bool operator () (const double lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs < rhs.a; }
};

int main() {
    vector<Foo> test;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        Foo foo = { i + 1, 'a' + i };

        test.push_back(foo);
    }

    cout << upper_bound(test.begin(), test.end(), 2, comp())->b << endl;
}
```

This works fine on [Visual Studio 2015](http://rextester.com/MWKBY89523). But Visual Studio 2008 gives me the error:

> error C2664: 'bool comp::operator ()(const double,const Foo &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Foo' to 'const double'

I suspect that there is some evil in the implementation where the functor is tested for strict weak ordering by swapping the inputs. Is there a workaround to suspend that checking on the compiler, or do I just have to just change my functor to taking in 2 `Foo`s and make a temporary `Foo` to represent the 2 here?

Comment: "I am stuck using Visual Studio 2008" Who did this to you?! :(

Comment: @tambre TRUMP! \*shakes fist\*

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, and.. It fails to compile only in Debug version (compiles fine in Release). And it happens because `if (!_Pred(_Left, _Right)) return (false); else if (_Pred(_Right, _Left)) _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid operator<", _Where, _Line);` in `_Debug_lt_pred` function. Where it tries to check the predicate works correctly, by checking that its result changes, when you switch the arguments. :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Is there a way to prevent the debug compilation somehow?

Comment: @JonathanMee That, I do not know. This is why it's a comment, rather than an answer. I just decided to share my observations about the issue.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It seems disabling `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is a common solution online. I'm unhappy with that... but then I'm unhappy with Visual Studio 2008. Ultimately I decided to go with conditional compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [stated by Algirdas Preidžius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299656/upper-bound-with-binary-function-visual-studio-2008-bug#comment71754426_42299656) this is a Debug only implementation error in Visual Studio 2008. It has been corrected on [visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010).

The bug is in Microsoft's C++ implementation code and it's gated by [`_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985939(v=vs.90).aspx) so if disabling that is an option consider adding "_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0" to your "Preprocessor Definitions".

If you don't like the idea of disabling iterator checking you'll need to workaround by disabling `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` so your code will look something like:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    char b;
};

int main() {
    vector<Foo> test;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        Foo foo = { i + 1, 'a' + i };

        test.push_back(foo);
    }

#if _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING
    for(vector<Foo>::const_iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it) {
        if(it->a > 2) {
            cout << it->b << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
#else
    struct comp : public binary_function<const double, const Foo&, bool> {
        bool operator () (const double lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs < rhs.a; }
    };

    cout << upper_bound(test.begin(), test.end(), 2, comp())->b << endl;
#endif
}
```

A couple notes here:

1. Note that I'm using a `#if` which means the `if`-block will only execute if `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is defined and is non-0. At design time Visual Studio 2008 seems to always think that it is undefined
2. My code defines `comp` inline if your particular situation requires `comp` to by used in multiple places 1<sup>st</sup> consider wrapping this entire `else`-block in a function to limit the number of `#define`s in your code, obviously the applicability of this comment will be limited if you're using `comp` in multiple standard algorithms

Answer (score -1):

As already [Algirdas Preidžius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5440453/algirdas-preid%C5%BEius) mentioned it is because of [strict weak orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) checking.

As a workaround you can define both operators.

```
struct comp {
    bool operator () (const double lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs < rhs.a; }
    bool operator () (const Foo& lhs, const double rhs) { return lhs.a < rhs; }
};
```

Comment: Nope, results in the exact same error. And how could it change? The function checking weak ordering is calling a single function `_Pred` twice while swapping arguments.